# airflow2.0: Segmentation fault (core dumped) upon pip3 install 'apache-airflow[amazon]'

Tags: segmentation-fault, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I need to use ECSOperator. Upon migration from Airflow1.10.13 to Airflow2.0, when I installed **pip3 install 'apache-airflow[amazon]'** it gave segmentation error. Before that all Dag's were working in Airflow. Reference: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/operators/ecs.html#howto-operator-ecsoperator .
Can someone please let me know where am I wrong. How to correct this segmentation fault, as scheduler has stopped running after this issue.

Result:

````
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, six, cryptography, PyJWT, werkzeug, itsdangerous, markupsafe, jinja2, click, flask, Flask-JWT-Extended, sqlalchemy, Flask-SQLAlchemy, PyYAML, apispec, attrs, zipp, importlib-metadata, pyrsistent, setuptools, jsonschema, pytz, Babel, Flask-Babel, marshmallow, marshmallow-enum, marshmallow-sqlalchemy, python-dateutil, defusedxml, python3-openid, Flask-OpenID, dnspython, idna, email-validator, flask-login, colorama, prison, WTForms, flask-wtf, sqlalchemy-utils, flask-appbuilder, psutil, apache-airflow-providers-sqlite, setproctitle, gunicorn, urllib3, chardet, certifi, requests, inflection, clickclick, openapi-spec-validator, swagger-ui-bundle, connexion, flask-caching, python-editor, Mako, alembic, cached-property, text-unidecode, python-slugify, python-nvd3, typing, sqlalchemy-jsonfield, thrift, tabulate, colorlog, typing-extensions, pygments, lockfile, docutils, python-daemon, flask-swagger, tzlocal, json-merge-patch, tenacity, pep562, importlib-resources, unicodecsv, natsort, croniter, graphviz, lazy-object-proxy, dataclasses, commonmark, rich, marshmallow-oneofschema, apache-airflow-providers-http, funcsigs, apache-airflow-providers-ftp, apache-airflow-providers-imap, iso8601, argcomplete, dill, numpy, pandas, markdown, cattrs, pytzdata, pendulum, termcolor, jmespath, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, watchtower, apache-airflow-providers-amazon, apache-airflow
Segmentation fault (core dumped)```

Please find the screenshot attached below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZazNy.png
````

Answer (score 0):

To avoid issues with upgrading to Airflow 2.0 you need to follow the [official guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-to-2.html)

First you need upgrading to 1.10.14 (bridge release) and use the `upgrade_check` tool to detect all issues needs to be addressed.

Specifically your issue is because for Airflow 2.0 you need to install [amazon package](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/) as

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon
```

Then you can import the operator as:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs import ECSOperator
```

Comment: I upgraded successfully to 2.0. This issue was encountered while installing the amazon package. Regarding imports, I read the guide and have followed same steps, the Dag is working fine on my second setup with Airflow 2.0.0.

Comment: @Sherr so what is the issue?

Comment: Thanks. I tested this on 4 machines and the actual issue I am encountering is while installing the package 'apache-airflow[amazon]'. This leads to Segmentation fault. It happened on 2 of the setups. But working fine on other setups.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your system is misconfigured to install wrong pip packages. PIP Packages (and there can be any of them - I suspects some amazon library) come in a binary or source form. Bitnary form matches the system you are installing it on. If for whatever reason, the configuration of the system was modified and for example different set of glibc was installed or generally the system was heavily modified on the "OS" level, you might get packages installed that expect some dynamic libraries to be present but they are not, or with a wrong version. That might lead to such behaviour.

The probable solution is to reinstall airflow with:

`pip install .... --no-binary :all: --force-reinstall`

This might take much longer and might require adding some build dependencies because the binary packages will be recompiled.

Note that this is not a problem with `apache-airflow` or `apache-airflow-providers-amazon` packages. Those are pure python and they should install cleanly, it's likely one of the dependencies of the `amazon` provider, but there are many (inlcuding transitive dependencies), so it is hard to say which creates the problem.